# Xcode7 not showing TabBar in tab bar iOS app

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, xcode7

I had an app that worked fine 2 years ago developed with xcode 5/6, I tried to upgrade it today with Xcode 7.2. The app is a tabbar application and has a custom keyboard where the tabbar is always sitting on top of the custom keyboard. However with the Xcode 7.2, I noticed there is a new Apple bar that comes along and sits on top of my tabbar now and thus hides my tabbar. Is there a way to hide this new bar? It has undo and redo buttons that I don't need for my app anyways. (See image attached).[image]

Comment: Answered here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696129/how-to-hide-toolbar-in-newer-ios