# How to hide Toolbar in newer iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, toolbar, tabbar

I upgraded an older version(ios6) of a tabbed based app to latest iOS. The app uses my own customkeyboard like showing in the image attached. The tabbar supposed to stay on top of the keyboard, but with new iOS versions, I get this new toolbar by default. How do I get rid of this bar because it's sitting on top of my tabbar?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UITextInputAssistantItem* item = [textField inputAssistantItem];
item.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
item.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing on the top is a suggestion list.

I just tested this in Xcode. The way to hide is to disable auto-correction. Do it programmatically or using storyboard by highlighting search bar.

searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your suggestion did not work for me, I tried both from Storyboard and programatically. The answer above by arturdev did work for me though.